# How to disable "This document has embedded..." pop-ups in Okular?

Tags: kubuntu, okular

How to disable pop-ups at the top of **okular**

> "This document has embedded files. Click here to see them or go to
>   File -> Embedded files".

Is it possible? I haven't found a setting for this.

Comment: This may eliminate too many info and error messages but the required message is blocked by unchecking: Settings -> Configure Okular -> General -> Show hints and messages. If this answers your question I will draft a formal answer...

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes, it works

Comment: Great news! I have made a formal answer to the question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There does not seem to be a *specific* setting for this particular 'info' message but if you turn off *all* such messages you will achieve the desired effect.

*Uncheck* the following setting:

```
Settings -> Configure Okular -> General -> Show hints and messages
```

And all should be well! Below is a screenshot demonstrating the required setting on my own system:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to press F5 ( or do File -> Reload ) to get rid of the message on an already opened document.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the message "This document has forms. Click on the button to interact with them, or use View -> Show Forms."... :-(

Comment: There is now a dedicated option called "Notify about embedded files, forms, or signatures" in the same menu.