# How to disable "This document has forms..." info in Okular

Tags: okular

I'm constantly changing a PDF (actually an `animate`d LaTeX document), but every time Okular reloads the document, it shows a HUGE popup saying:

> This document has forms. Click on the button to interact with them, or use View -> Show Forms.

How can I disable this?

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892692/how-to-disable-this-document-has-embedded-pop-ups-in-okular), but it doesn't work for this particular pop-up.

Comment: For me is even worst because my document has forms and is also digitally signed, so when Okular reloads I have two popoups: > This document has forms. Click on the button to interact with them, or use View -> Show Forms. > This document is digitally signed.

Comment: @Claudio maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892692/how-to-disable-this-document-has-embedded-pop-ups-in-okular) will work at least for the second popup.